# Clearing message jQuery delay setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I clear the field message after a couple seconds using delay jQuery function instead of setTimeout? The code below will clear value immediately.

```
    var $this = $(this),
            mid = $this.find("#emid"),
            contents = $this.find("#equestion");    

    if(contents.length<30){
      contents.css('color','red')
      .val('Error Message')
      .delay(5000)
      .val('');
      }
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is the neatest option here.

Comment: You can't. `.delay` is for animations; `setTimeout` is basically for everything else. I'm sure `.delay` uses `setTimeout` internally as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPD: Actually, you can simply use the default queue and freely chain effects (like `show`) and non-effects (like `val`). Just wrap the latter in a `queue`-`dequeue` call:

```
$("input")
    .queue(function() { $(this).val("blah").dequeue() })
    .delay(1000)
    .queue(function() { $(this).val("").dequeue() })
    .fadeOut(1000) // etc
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cA4jB/1/

/UPD

No, you don't have to (and actually shouldn't) use setTimeout. jQuery provides a nice built-in mechanism for this, called [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/). The basic idea is like this: you "collect" functions or delays in a named queue:

```
 $(elem).queue("queueName", function(next) { do something and call next() });
 $(elem).queue("queueName", function(next) { do something else and call next() });
 $(elem).delay(3000, "queueName");
 $(elem).queue("queueName", function(next) { do something else and call next() });
```

and then call `dequeue()` to start processing:

```
 $(elem).dequeue("queueName")
```

Each function in the queue is called one after another, and delays work as expected.

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/cA4jB/

Comment: Interesting. I like this a lot, makes sense, Thank you.

Comment: @Codex73: actually, the solution is even simpler. I updated the post.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery documentation clearly mentions that

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

So, its better to use the setTimeout function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky, but you can create an animation that does almost nothing, with a callback that yould clear the value.

```
if(contents.length<30){
    contents.css('color','red')
        .val('Error Message').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 5000, function() {
            contents.val('');
        });
}
```

The best way is still to use setTimeout